# If both $A-\frac{1}{2}I$ and $A + \frac{1}{2}I$ are orthogonal matrices, then....

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem :

If both $A-\frac{1}{2}I$ and $A + \frac{1}{2}I$ are orthogonal matrices, then which one of the following is correct :

(i) A is orthogonal

(2) A is skew symmetric matrix of even order

(3) $A^2 = \frac{3}{4}I$

Solution :

$(A'-\frac{1}{2}I)(A-\frac{1}{2}I) =I$  and $(A'+\frac{1}{2}I)(A+\frac{1}{2}I) =I$

$\Rightarrow A +A' =0$

$\Rightarrow A' =-A $

$\Rightarrow A^2 = -\frac{3}{4}I$  ....(i)

$\Rightarrow (-\frac{3}{4})^n =(det(A))^2$  ....(ii)

$\Rightarrow $ n is even . ......(iii)

Request you to please explain how (i) came and further (ii) and (iii) thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since we find that $A'=-A$ then

$$\left(A'+\frac12I\right)\left(A+\frac12I\right)=I\iff\left(-A+\frac12I\right)\left(A+\frac12I\right)=I\\\iff\frac14I-A^2=I\iff A^2=-\frac34I$$

Now take the determinant

$$\det(A^2)=(\det(A))^2=\det\left(-\frac34I\right)=\left(-\frac34\right)^n\ge0\implies n\;\text{is even}$$

Comment: Note that the multiplication proceeds as $\left(-A+\frac12I\right)\left(A+\frac12I\right)$ $=-A\cdot A+\frac12I\cdot A-A\cdot\frac12I+\frac12I\cdot\frac12I$ $=-A^2+\frac12A-\frac12A+\frac14I^2$ $=-A^2+\frac14I$; it's not true that $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$ for arbitrary matrices (like it is for numbers), but it works in this case since the two matrices commute.