# If $(A-I/2)$ and $(A+I/2)$ are orthogonal matrices then how to show $A$ is skew symmetric matrix of even order?

Tags: matrices

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189650/if-both-a-frac12i-and-a-frac12-are-orthogonal-matrices-then) question I cannot understand the last step by the user.How is $|-\frac{3}{4} I|=(-3/4)^n$ ?Should'nt it be just $-\frac{3}{4}$ ?

Moreover the OP did not prove that $A$ cannot be orthogonal.How to prove that?

Comment: When we multiply a matrix by a scalar, then every entry of the matrix is multiplied by that scalar. In this case all diagonal entries are multiplied by $-3/4$ And determinant is the product of diagonal entries(since this is a diagonal matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Hint that is a determinant sign not a mod sign . $det (kA)=k^n.det(A)$ here $k=-3/4,A=I$ so its $(-3/4)^n$. Test for orthogonal matrix is that $A.A^{T}=I$ thats all.

Comment: Thanks but there's another part to my question....^(orthogonality)

Comment: @SanchayanDutta the determinant of orthogonal matrices is $\pm 1$. But in this case......

Comment: @AnuragA can you tell me why is it 1 or -1 ?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta use the definition of orthogonal matrices. $AA^{t}=I$. Now use the multiplicative property of determinants and the fact that $\det(A)=\det(A^{t})$.

Comment: @AnuragA Got it.Thanks!

Comment: @ sanchayandutta i have edited